# Ubuntu installer freezes while installing grub2

Tags: boot, grub2, software-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu desktop on my pc. During the installation, the installer freezes when installing the grub2 package. I have retried several times and it gets stuck in the same spot every time. I have tried the latest version as well as an older version. any help would be appreciated. TYIA

Comment: If you expand the details of the installation progress (click the little triangle next to the status text, [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/f36ZU.jpg)), what is the last thing you see ? Maybe it isn't actually frozen / hung - it does take a few mins.

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS. Are you installing UEFI or BIOS boot mode? And then if UEFI, do you have the ESP - efi system partition. If BIOS is drive MBR or gpt. If gpt do you have bios_grub partition? Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: It is definitely freezing... the mouse curser freezes and becomes unresponsive as well..IDK if it is UEFI or BIOS, I am just installing by the default.

Comment: ESP is one of the three partitions that is created.